# Time for rebus # 23

Tags: rebus

This is a very common 4-word phrase:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> For the time being?

because

> 4 times and a bee?

Comment: That's it! You got it!  :)

Comment: _Grumble._ I don't know, but that's rather loose. I mean, it has "fo(u)r" and "time" and "be(e)" in it, but all in the wrong forms. Never mind, well done, I guess.

Comment: @MOehm:  Please feel free to enter your version (not changing mine, but making up a new, improved one). :D